# Define a @property and @classproperty with the same name (Python, Django)

Tags: python, django

### Background

The Django `LiveServerTestCase` class has a `live_server_url` method with a `@classproperty` decorator. (`django.utils.functional.classproperty`.) The class starts its test server before any tests run, and thus knows the test server's URL before any tests run.

I have a similar `MyTestCase` class that has a `live_server_url` `@property`. It starts a new test server before each test, and thus its `live_server_url` property can't be a `@classproperty` because it doesn't know its port until it is instantiated.

To make the API for both consistent, so that all the test utility functions etc. in the code base can be used with both classes, the tests could be written to never reference `live_server_url` in `setUpClass()`, before all the tests run. But this would slow down many tests.

Instead, I want `MyTestCase.live_server_url` to raise a helpful error if it is referenced from the class object rather than an instance object.

Since `MyTestCase.live_server_url` is a `@property`, `MyTestCase().live_server_url` returns a string, but `MyTestCase.live_server_url` returns a property object. This causes cryptic errors like  `"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'property' and 'str'"`.

### Actual question

If I could define a `@classproperty` and `@property` on the same class, then I would define a `MyTestCase.live_server_url` `@classproperty` that raises an error with a helpful message like "live_server_url can only be called on an instance of MyTestCase, not on the MyTestCase class".

But when you define 2 methods with the same name in a Python class then the earlier one gets discarded, so I can't do that.

How can I make the behavior of `MyTestCase.live_server_url` different depending on whether it is called on the class or on an instance?

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to use a metaclass. ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69808716/724752))

But since I read that metaclasses should usually be avoided, here is what I did:

```
from django.utils.functional import classproperty


class MyTestCase(TransactionTestCase):
    def __getattribute__(self, attr: str):
        if attr == 'live_server_url':
            return "http://%s:%s" % (self.host, self._port)
        
        return super().__getattribute__(attr)
    
    @classproperty
    def live_server_url(self):
        raise ValueError('live_server_url can only be called on an instance of MyTestCase, not on the MyTestCase class')
```

`MyTestCase().live_server_url` calls `__getattribute__()`.

`MyTestCase.live_server_url` calls the `@classproperty` definition of `live_server_url`.

Answer (score 0):

Just subclass `property` and implement `__get__` to raise on error if it is not accessed through an instance :

```
class OnlyInstanceProperty(property):
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            raise ValueError('live_server_url can only be called on an instance of MyTestCase, not on the MyTestCase class')
        return super().__get__(obj, objtype)
```

Perhaps you can come up with a better name for it. But in any case, you can then use it like so:

```
class MyTestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.host = "foo"
        self._port = "bar"
    @OnlyInstanceProperty
    def live_server_url(self):
        return "http://%s:%s" % (self.host, self._port)
```

Then:

```
print(MyTestClass.live_server_url)  # http://foo:bar
print(MyTestClass.live_server_url)  # ValueError: live_server_url can only be called on an instance of MyTestCase, not on the MyTestCase class
```

And it will work like any other property, so you can use `live_server_url.setter` and `live_server_url.deleter`

If you are unfamiliar with `__get__`, [read this HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) and it should tell you all you need to know about descriptors, which are an intermediate/advanced Python technique. The descriptor protocol is behind a lot of seemingly magical behavior, and that HOWTO shows you how various things like `classmethod`, `staticmethod`, `property` could be implemented in pure python using the descriptor protocol.

Note, you don't have to inherit from `property`, a simple bespoke (albeit tightly coupled) approach could be something like:

```
class LiveServerUrl:
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            raise ValueError('live_server_url can only be called on an instance of MyTestCase, not on the MyTestCase class')
        return "http://%s:%s" % (obj.host, obj._port)

class MyTestClass:
    live_server_url = LiveServerUrl()
    def __init__(self):
        self.host = "foo"
        self._port = "bar"
```